# Batch: Copy file form source to destination - Cannot find file specified error

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, copy

I have a folders structure, where each folder has one excel file that I want to copy to new destination.

Example:

Source path:  C:\Data\0. MyFolder\1. Templates\00. Folder 0\File.xlsb

Destination path:  C:\Data\0. MyFolder\NewFolder\00. Folder 0\File.xlsb

The "00. Folder 0" is a name stored in array. So I use a for loop to create a new directory based on the names in the array and I create the new similar structure.

I'm getting the message "The system cannot find the file specified." when trying to copy one file from one folder to another folder.

When I print the path of file it seems correct. what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Generate Subfolders
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "batch_path=%~dp0"
SET "first_folder=01. Folder1"
SET "second_folder=02. Folder2"
SET "third_folder=03. Folder3"

:: Create the new Working Data folder
SET /p new_folder_name= Enter Directory Name: 
SET "full_path=%batch_path%%new_folder_name%"

ECHO Working...

IF NOT EXIST ("%full_path%") (
  MKDIR %new_folder_name%
  IF "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
    ECHO Folder created successfully.
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO Error while creating folder.
  )
) ELSE (
  ECHO Folder already exists.
)

SET "folders_list="%first_folder%" "%second_folder%" "%third_folder%""
SET "templates_folder=C:\Data\0. MyFolder\1. Templates"

FOR %%f in (%folders_list%) DO (
    SET "updated_full_path=%full_path%\%%f"
    SET "template_full_path_file=!templates_folder!\%%~f\file.xlsb"
    :: Displays the path file correctly
    ECHO !template_full_path_file!
    MKDIR "!updated_full_path!"
    :: However I cannot copy the file to new destination
    COPY template_full_path_file updated_full_path
    PAUSE
)
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: Inconsequent handling of quotes. `%%f` contains alreday quoted strings and it should be `SET "updated_full_path=%full_path%\%%~f"` and as @SAhmad already pointed out the `!` are missing but since the pathes contain spaces they have to be quoted too: `COPY "!template_full_path_file!" "!updated_full_path!"`

Comment: @LotPings Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resolving paths in `copy` command.

`COPY "!template_full_path_file!" "!updated_full_path!"`

Comment: Thank you so much! I also add double quotes as @LotPings suggested.

Comment: Nice catch! Updated the answer.